# Delete line on Windows CMD in Perl

Tags: perl, cmd

I am trying to Format the Output inside of a Perl Script. By this, i want to overwrite text in the Console. I already got it to overwrite a line, but i cant go back another line.
For example

```
print "test\ntest";
print "\rhi  ";
```

Will Output

```
 Test
 Hi
```

What i know want to do, is going a line further up, so that instead of the second test, the first test can be replaced. \b does nothing in my console, is there another way to go back a line on the Windows cmd?

Answer (score 2):

```
print  "\e[H";              # Put the cursor on the first line
print  "\e[J";              # Clear from cursor to end of screen
print  "\e[H\e[J";          # Clear entire screen (just a combination of the above)
print  "\e[K";              # Clear to end of current line (as stated previously)
print  "\e[m";              # Turn off character attributes (eg. colors)
printf "\e[%dm", $N;        # Set color to $N (for values of 30-37, or 100-107)
printf "\e[%d;%dH", $R, $C; # Put cursor at row $R, column $C (good for "drawing")
```

Also see

- [Term::Screen::Uni](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::Screen::Uni)
- [Term::Cap](http://search.cpan.org/~jstowe/Term-Cap-1.17/Cap.pm)
- [Curses](https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses)

Comment: print  "\e[H\e[J";    gives me -> "test←[H←[Jhi" on my Console. Same goes for K and M. Those seem to not work with Windows CMD on my System. Will read the "also see" 's now.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a good programming practice but it will give the result you are looking for. Now you can apply the logic and rewrite it as per your requirement.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
my $output="Hi";
#local $| = 1;

print "test\ntest";
print ("\b" x length("test"));
for(my $i=0;$i<length("test");$i++)
{
    $output .=" ";
}
print $output;
```

**output:**

```
D:\Study\perl>perl test1.pl
test
Hi
```

this \b will take the cursor 4 step back  as the length of "test" is 4. so the next line that you are going to print should be in length equal to 4 or more. as length of "hi" is less than 4 so I added 2 white spaces using for loop, otherwise it will give you an output like "Hist";

Comment: Well, this is the Approach that i already got, that did not get me to my target. I want to move one line up. I added to spaces to my Hi string, so it will print Hi instead of Hist. But i wanted Hi  \ntest instead of test\nHi. With the \b you seem to be not able to move back over a linebreak

Comment: why you want to go one line up to achieve the same result ?

Comment: My Situation is I want to Change more than one line written onto the Screen. And thats why i have to go back one line up. This is just a small example to show what i want to do, but as written in my initial post, the crucial part is editing the first and not the second line. How i am able to edit the second line was already answered in my question